# Are sets internally sorted, or is the __str__ method displaying a sorted list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, set

I have a `set`, I add items (ints) to it, and when I print it, the items apparently are sorted:

```
a = set()
a.add(3)
a.add(2)
a.add(4)
a.add(1)
a.add(5)

print a
# set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

I have tried with various values, apparently it needs to be only ints.

I run Python 2.7.5 under MacOSX. It is also reproduced using repl.it (see http://repl.it/TpV)

The question is: is this documented somewhere (haven't find it so far), is it normal, is it something that can be relied on?

Extra question: when is the sort done? during the print? is it internally stored sorted? (is that even possible given the expected constant complexity of insertion?)

Comment: I think it is cpython implementation detail, because the hash of an int is the int and under the hood, sets are implemented like a dict with null values

Comment: The simple rule is that it isn't documented, you can't rely on it -- because things that aren't documented can change in future releases, or differ between implementations of the language (CPython vs Stackless vs PyPy vs IronPython vs Jython, etc).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a coincidence. The data is neither sorted nor does `__str__` sort.

The hash values for integers equal their value (except for `-1` and long integers outside the `sys.maxint` range), which *increases the chance* that integers are slotted in order, but that's not a given.

`set` uses a hash table to track items contained, and ordering depends on the hash value, *and* insertion and deletion history.

The how and why of the interaction between integers and sets are all implementation details, and can easily vary from version to version. Python 3.3 introduced hash randomisation for certain types, and Python 3.4 expanded on this, making ordering of sets and dictionaries volatile between Python process restarts too (depending on the types of values stored).

Comment: but it is quite amazing. `a = range(100); random.shuffle(a); list(set(a)) == range(100); #True` !

Comment: @njzk2: Again, that's only because for most integers, `hash(integer) == integer`, which helps them land in sequential slots in the hash table. But this depends on the insertion and deletion history too.

Comment: yes, I have noticed that inserting some strings in the middle can set this off.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is a _coincidence_.  There is a reason it happens.

Comment: @wim: I explain the reason. But mix in other types and collision opportunities go way up.